# pgfmathsetmacro changes when it shouldn't and vice versa

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath, groupplots

I try to generate a groupplot dynamically. In general this works except of a variable extracted from a table.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
    1   -1  \\
    2   -2  \\
    3   3   \\
    4   4   \\
}\mytable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof\mytable
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[height=4cm, group style={group size=2 by \numberofrows}]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\numberofrows}{\numberofrows-1}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofrows}{

        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]0}\of\mytable
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numberofsample}{\pgfplotsretval}

        \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]1}\of\mytable
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\valueofsample}{\pgfplotsretval}

        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot {\valueofsample};
            \node [anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0.05,0.95) {sample=\numberofsample};

        \nextgroupplot
            \addplot {\valueofsample};
            \node [anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs: 0.05,0.95) {sample=\numberofsample};     % numberofsample has changed?!?
    }
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code should generate a 2 x N groupplot. The variable `\numberofsample` (first column of the table) as well as `\valueofsample` (second column of the table) should change row-wise and should be constant in a column. Instead, it produces the following indeterministic output:

[image: Output of MWE]

`\valueofsample` never changes and `\numberofsample` is going wild?!?

Comment: What are you plotting the value of the sample against?

Comment: Here it's just a constant value for illustrating the value of `\valueofsample`. In my real document `\valueofsample` is used to read and plot a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the output you want, but it demonstrates how to overcome the particular problems you ask about. I don't know how to create 8 plots from only 4 single values. I've created 4 plots, taking each value to be the y coordinate for a single point, with the x coordinate as 0.

You need to save the definitions globally and to expand them fully for this to work, and any annotations you want need to be done in the options given to the plot. You can't use the values to create a node afterwards, as far as I can tell - it is simply too late.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=crcr]{
    1   -1  \\
    2   -2  \\
    3   3   \\
    4   4   \\
}\mytable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof\mytable
\pgfmathsetmacro\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{groupplot}[height=4cm, group style={group size=1 by \numberofrows}]

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\numberofrows}{\numberofrows-1}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofrows}{
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]0}\of\mytable
      \xdef\numberofsample{\pgfplotsretval}

      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{[index]1}\of\mytable
      \xdef\valueofsample{\pgfplotsretval}

      \nextgroupplot[title/.expanded={sample=\numberofsample}]
      \addplot  coordinates {(0,\valueofsample)};
    }
  \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: 4 plots]

Hopefully, you can adapt this to your requirements, since I don't understand what you're trying to do, but you presumably do!

Comment: Yes, with this I got my issue working. Thank you very much! The second column should have been an exact copy of the first one. Here, it illustrated that `\numberofsample` changed nondeterministically without touching it. \\ Anyway, for what is `\pgfmathsetmacro` good for if it can change anytime it wants? Additionally, I still don't understand why even the globally `\xdef\numberofsample{...}` changes when using in a node instead of the plot itself. When the node command is called it still has the correct value...

Comment: @Chickenmarkus I'm not sure. You'd have to look at the way the group plots are typeset. I suspect that the code may be collected and then typeset later, but that the `\node` is not treated along with the plot. So you end up with the plots getting the global, expanded values, but what ends up in the nodes isn't necessarily what would be in the nodes, if they were grouped in with the plots. But I really don't know.